# MathTime Pro 2 fonts with beamer - Error: Command `\lll' already defined

Tags: beamer, fonts, mtpro

MathTime Professional 2 doesn't work with Beamer. Did anyone encounter the same problem? Below short example:

```
\documentclass[10pt, xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{polski}
\usepackage[polish]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}


\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usepackage[subscriptcorrection]{mtpro2}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ptm}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Title}
Short $x+Y$  
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I get an error message

```
! LaTeX Error: Command `\lll' already defined.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.1422 ...bol{\lll}          {\mathrel}{AMSa}{"6E}
```

The problem disappears when switching to the other fonts. Does anybody have a suggestion how to fix it?
It might be important to add that for `\documentclass{article}` MathTime Pro 2 works with minor modification the preamble.

Comment: The problem is that `beamer` automatically loads `amssymb`, which shouldn't be loaded with `mtpro2`. Try with the `noamssymb` option to `beamer`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: @egreg: Thank you. After adding `noamssym` I had to remove `\usepackage[polish]{babel}` in order to get the output. Unfortunately, this switches times fonts (for text, math fonts works) into default beamer fonts.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The fault is in two places.

First problem: with `mtpro2` one shouldn't load `amssymb`. This is done automatically by `beamer`, but can be prevented with the option `noamssymb`:

```
\documentclass[10pt,xcolor=dvipsnames,noamssymb]{beamer}
```

Second problem: the `babel` language definition file `polish.ldf` defines `\lll` for to me mysterious reasons.

Possible fix:

```
\documentclass[10pt,xcolor=dvipsnames,noamssymb]{beamer}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{polski}
\usepackage[polish]{babel}

%%% fix for \lll
\let\babellll\lll
\let\lll\relax


\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usepackage[subscriptcorrection]{mtpro2}

%%% fix for \lll
\let\mathlll\lll
\let\lll\babellll


\begin{document}

...
```

In case you need the `\lll` math symbol, use `\mathlll`.

Note that loading `amsmath` and `graphicx` is not required with `beamer`, that loads them automatically.

Comment: Thank you - it works. I used `\usepackage{newtxtext}` instead of `\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ptm}` because time fonts don't show on a presentation. By the way: loading `amsmath` is require because mtpro2 disables this package.

Answer (score 1):

The problem causes `\usepackage[polish]{babel}` and `\usepackage{amssymb}` in the same file. The solution is simply to **change the order** of these two packeges (`amssymb` should go first). In your case `mtpro2` should go first - because `mtpro2` apparently loads `amssymb`.

Comment: I know that I've just posted an answer for 8-years-old question but it might be helpful for others.

Comment: The conjecture that `mtpro2` loads `amssymb` is correct only if `mtpro2` is loaded with the option `amssymbols`.